# HashSet doesn't remove an object

Tags: c#, hashset

Probably I miss something using a HashSet and HashCode, but I don´t know why this doesn't work as I thought. I have an object with the HashCode is overridden. I added the object to a HashSet and later I change a property (which is used to calculate the HashCode) then I can´t remove the object.

```
public class Test 
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (Code==null)?0: Code.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public void TestFunction()
{
    var test = new Test();
    System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Test> hashSet = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Test>();
    hashSet.Add(test);
    test.Code = "Change";

    hashSet.Remove(test);  //this doesn´t remove from the hashset
}
```

Comment: Yes. Why do you expect other behavior? Make sure to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx .

Comment: I suggest removing your implementation of `GetHashCode` and allowing the .NET Framework to handle generating it for you. You only need to override it if you need to define some kind of value-equivalence. If you want to use `Code` as a key then use `Dictionary<Code,OtherData>` rather than a `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: `null` is different to `"Change"`, that's why the `HashSet` cannot find it anymore. [Erip Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx): _"Guideline: the integer returned by GetHashCode should never change

Ideally, the hash code of a mutable object should be computed from only fields which cannot mutate, and therefore the hash value of an object is the same for its entire lifetime."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter: No, there are no empty strings involved here, and it's not the string equality that matters anyway. The initial value of `Code` is `null`, leading to a hash code of 0. If the hash code of `"Change"` *also* happened to be 0 by massive coincidence, then it would find the value.

Comment: If the object is the same, "remove" method should remove it, shouldn´t it?

Comment: @JonSkeet: sorry, i thought it were initialized with `""`, however, the reason is the same since you cannot change the implementation of `String.GetHashCode`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Nope - again, nothing is testing for string equality. If the *hash codes* matched, then the set would test the two values (the one in the set and the one being passed into `Remove`) for equality. They're the same reference, so will be deemed equal. It's not like the set has taken a *copy* of the original object... and even if it had, there's no `Equals` override to compare the strings.

Comment: @user3759554 your really should read the article... While remove should remove object, it will not because it can't find it by hash code.

Comment: Your name is Mary Smith, and you put a file about yourself in a file folder labeled "S". Then you change your name to Mary Jones, and you look for the file in a folder called "J". The file is supposed to be in a folder based on your last name, so why don't you find it?  Now is it clear to you why what you are doing is wrong and you must never do it?  If you change the hash key then *you have to remove the item from the dictionary before you change it and put it back in afterwards*, just like you have to move the paper from "S" to "J" when you change your name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you're overriding `GetHashCode` but not overriding `Equals`. Don't do that. They should always be overridden at the same time, in a consistent manner.

Next, you're right that changing an objects hash code *will* affect finding it in any hash-based data structures. After all, the first part of checking for the presence of a key in a hash-based structure is to find *candidate* equal values by quickly finding all existing entries with the same hash code. There's no way that the data structure can "know" that the hash code has been changed and update its own representation.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) makes this clear:

> You can override `GetHashCode` for immutable reference types. In general, for mutable reference types, you should override `GetHashCode` only if:
>
> - You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable; or
> - You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.

Comment: I didn´t write the equals method because I want to keep the focus in my question. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user3759554: But Equals and GetHashCode are fundamentally tied together. If your *actual* implementation includes it, you should include it in the question. I appreciate the aim of keeping the code focused (really, I do!) but this is a bit of a special case :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void TestFunction()
{
    var test = new Test();
    System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Test> hashSet = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Test>();
    test.Code = "Change";
    hashSet.Add(test);

    hashSet.Remove(test);  //this doesn´t remove from the hashset
}
```

first set the value into object of Test, then add it to HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

HashCode is used to find object in the `HashSet`/ `Dictionary`. If hash code changed object no longer can be found in the `HashSet` because when looked up by new HashSet the bucket for items with that new hash code will not (most likely) contain the object (which is in bucket marked with old hash code).

Note that after initial search by hash code `Equals` will be used to perform final match, but it does not apply to your particular case as you have the same object and use default Equals that compares references.

Detailed explanation/guidelines - [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert).